# Send alerts when post is read

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-alerts

I'm wondering whether SharePoint can send alerts to the administrators when blog posts get read. We want to track how many people (if any at all) are reading technical blog posts.

I have found a way to set alerts for when items change, but not when they get viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this would not be possible with a "simple" solution - as in out-of-the-box. There is no "viewed item" event in any way.

You would either have to tap the SharePoint Analytics database and check when a specific user has viewed a specific page and upon that event send a mail. You most likely would have to code a timer job for that which checks in regular intervals for this.
Another (simpler) method would be to just have a small WebPart embedded on the blog post page which tracks who has viewed the page and sends alerts.

You should rethink what you are doing in any case. There is no good measure of when somebody really has read a blog post. Did somebody read the blog post if he just entered the URL? Maybe the click was an error and the user leaves the page right away. Maybe you only activate the "read" flag after a certain amount of time - how would you determine the time spent in the stateless web? With a JavaScript timer being started when the user arrives at the page, stopped when he leaves the page? How would you send the "stop" signal if the user just closes the browser?

You can track if a user **visited** a page - that does not mean he read the article / blog post. The only sure way to do that is to include a button on the page which says "I have read the blog post". Again, this button can be faked, i.e. just clicked without reading, but you have the users' word that he read the blog post. This would be the third solution and in my eyes best solution to track who has read a blog post: Implement a button which allows the user to mark a post as read. This could even be implemented nicely with a tracking-list, that list in turn could be subscribed to by an admin who would get automatic summaries of who has read an article, who hasn't.